# How to convert list to multiline string?

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
["Jargon", "Hello", "This", "Is", "Great"]
```

I want to populate a string with:

```
"""
{}
""".format(list-elements-besides-the-first)
```

Is there a simple one liner I could use to make it such that I can:

1. get all the elements of the array (besides the first element) and shove it into the {}?
2. Is it possible to make it so that each element shows up in its own line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
"""
{}
""".format("\n".join(items[1:]))
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [list slicing](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html#odbchelper.list.4.2) and [joining](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), that is:

```
yourList = ["Jargon", "Hello", "This", "Is", "Great"]
butFirst = yourList[1:]
eachInASeparateLine = "\n".join(butFirst)

print(eachInASeparateLine)
```

Answer (score 4):

I am not absolutely sure what you are asking, as your post is not very concise, but this will print each item, except the first on its own line:

```
lst = ["Jargon", "Hello", "This", "Is", "Great"]
print '\n'.join([i for i in lst[1:]])
```

The `\n` is used to cause a line break when used within a string. Use list slicing to perform the operation on  all elements *after* the first item. Using the `for` loop allows you to iterate over all elements within the chosen indices.

output:

```
Hello
This
Is
Great
```

Comment: What's the difference between `[i for i in lst[1:]]` and `lst[1:]`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `join()` method of string and list `slice` method.

e.g

```
>>> l = ["Jargon", "Hello", "This", "Is", "Great"]
>>> l[1:]
['Hello', 'This', 'Is', 'Great']
>>> result = "\n".join(l[1:])
>>> print result
Hello
This
Is
Great
>>>
```

Comment: I like this the most, very short and self contained.

Answer (score 0):

create a new list with item inside the "{}", then join them with new line

```
test = ["Jargon", "Hello", "This", "Is", "Great"]
group = '\n'.join([test[0]] + ['{'+item+'}' for item in test[1:]])
print(group)
```

output:

```
Jargon
{Hello}
{This}
{Is}
{Great}
```